# SQL Server : insert multiple select results into single row

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Not even sure how to ask this. Everything I can find with the verbiage I am using is talking about combining results from separate tables.

I have a single table and I need multiple select result to go into another table in a single row. So I need to insert a new row from several select/as/where queries that I need as one resulting row.

In a real basic sense I need this but 10+ results into a 10+ column row with a date/time reference.

```
Insert into [table2].[namealias1]
    Select [number] as namealias1 
    From [db].[table]
    Where [name] = 'name1'
```

Table1 (source)

```
[NAME]   [NUMBER]
```

Table2 (destination)

```
DATESTAMP  NameAlias1 NameAlias2
```

It has been a long time since I have done any SQL and I am looking for some advice and a push in the right direction. Even just some hints at the best way to attack this. This is on SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's supposed to be in the single row? One column for each number? If the query returns 100 rows are you expecting to have 100 columns in the single row?

Comment: first union everything into one table, then use your method to store

Comment: I am thinking I need a CTE or temp table.

Comment: One the single row would be the values(int) selected from the first table. I need to look up those values by name and record them on a single row. The entire first table is only ~200 rows and will probably never be more than 1000 rows. I need maybe 20 results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CTEs could help with your problem. You need something like this:

```
;WITH cte1 as
(
    select col1, col2, ... ,colN
    from table1
    where conditions_for_table1
),
cte2 as
(
    select col1, col2, ... ,colK
    from table2
    where conditions_for_table2
),
......
......

insert into destination_table( table columns here)
select c1.col1, c2.col3, c3.col5, ... , cM.colK /*choose desired columns from CTEs*/
from cte1 c1
left /*inner*/ join cte2 as c2 on c1.joining_column = c2.joining_column
left /*inner*/ join cte3 as c3 on c1.joining_column = c3.joining_column
.....
left /*inner*/ join cteM as cM on c1.joining_column = cM.joining_column
```

Comment: I was working with CTE yesterday but it doesn't carry over for multiple conditions. I need to select multiple rows by name and return the values from each selected row to a single row in table 2.

Comment: What is a single row? Maybe you should proceed with aggregating the data you've obtained from the CTEs.

Comment: So is this like assigning variables to the selected data?

Comment: I have a result from multiple select queries with a union in a single column. I need to capture that data and enter it into a select statement for an existing table. How can I reference the data and insert commas in the insert statement?

Comment: All of the data I need comes from a single column in the source. I know exactly how many rows I have because that is how many select statements I have.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method:

I declared a variable for each select statement result and used the variables in the insert statement.